# sudo doesn't work, but root user works

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sockets, unix

I am configuring a mesh visualization platform based on BATMAN which is called ALFRED (I guess the pun is intended by the makers!) and in doing so, a couple of commands need to be executed as the root user. I can easily run most of the commands using `sudo` but when I get to a `cat` command, `sudo` seems to not not have the required privileges. 
For instance, to get the ALFRED server running I execute

```
$ sudo alfred -i br0 -m
```

and it runs properly and executes the command. But when I want to write to the UNIX socket using ALFRED, I execute the following command intending to write the host name to socket 64

```
$ sudo cat /etc/hostname | alfred -s 64
```

and I get the error

```
can't connect to unix socket: Permission denied
```

But when I switch to root user manually by `su root` and run

```
cat /etc/hostname | alfred -s 64
```

the command executes properly with no errors given and when I exit the root user and come back with the regular user, I can read the socket by invoking

```
$ sudo alfred -r 64
```

which is very odd. Just to make it stranger than it is, I wrote the `cat /etc/hostname | alfred -s 64` command in a shell script and called it `alfred_start.sh`. Now I can easily run

```
$ sudo sh alfred_start.sh
```

and no errors are given.

I have found a way to work around the whole problem but the question still remains, WHY?

Are there different privileges associated with `root` that are not accessible through `sudo`?
I do not believe that BATMAN or ALFRED have anything to do with the whole matter and it probably has something to do with the permissions associated with writing to UNIX sockets. I would very much appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Note taken. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo is a normal command, which interacts with the calling shell in a normal way. In this pipeline:

```
sudo cat /etc/hostname | alfred -s 64
```

the command on the left is `sudo cat /etc/hostname`. It runs `cat` with elevated privileges. The command on the right has no `sudo` in it so the `alfred` process is not `sudo`-elevated.

Move the `sudo` to the right of the pipe. (I assume you don't need elevated privileges to read your `/etc/hostname`!)

If you ever do need to `sudo` an entire pipeline, you must tell sudo to create priveleged shell, which then executes the pipeline supplied as a string, like this:

```
sudo sh -c 'something | something'
```

Other examples can be found in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106663/41515)

Comment: This works right. Now I run
`$ cat /etc/hostname | sudo alfred -s 64`
and it runs perfectly. Thank you.